# Why it cause an "exc_bad_access" error?

Tags: exc-bad-access, nstimeinterval

a simple test--

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];

NSDate *date1 = [NSDate date];
NSDate *date2 = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:3];

NSTimeInterval timeBetween = [date1 timeIntervalSinceDate:date2];
NSLog(@"between: %@",timeBetween);    

}
```

It got an error in line "NSTimeInterval..."

> program received signal:
>   'EXC_BAD_ACCESS'

Would you tell me where is wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you're using a string format code instead of a number format code in your NSLog statement.  try:

```
NSLog(@"between: %f",timeBetween);
```